# startapp banner double size in hight end devices issue

Tags: layout, crash, size, banner, startapp

I implemented startapp banner in my application android
I add banner in overlay view android but the size of banner so big

that make crash my layout,
I seem height of banner is 90dp (normal is 50dp)

Someone have same problem, please tell me

Comment: Hi, same for me but it once worked. Did you solve it?

Comment: i change to admob for avoid this problem

Comment: I changed to http://appodeal.com/+register .They´ll come with banners in 3 weeks.I currently have an average eCPM of 7-10$ on my appodeal interstitials. I hate admob because I had an eCPM´s of 0.5 to 1.8 $, ridiculous...maybe you should try that too if you also have interstitials.best regards

Comment: I have huge invalid traffic in admob (more than 500$) so i think i need to change to other ads network, do you have any ideas for new ads network